# Creating native shared library with Android studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a Native (C++) share library in Android studio (it will be linked to another project). I created the Native project, but whatever I try, it seems I have to have at least one java file that calls a C++ API from that library, meaning I need another C++ file in my set of native files containing the function the Java file calls.
I do not want this additional file, because it will be part of the shared library. I just want to create a shared library. Any idea how to do it, or should I switch back to ndk_build and its set of makefiles?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement that by using cmake in android studio, refer to the url of here : https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake

1. add c++ source file you needed to the directory where you want
2. modify the script in CMakeLists.txt to add the library you want to build:

```
add_library(
        anyLibName
        STATIC (or SHARED)
        absolute path of some c++ source file
)
```

3.include the c++ header files:

```
include_directories(directory absolute path of your c++ headers file)
```

4.execute 'Sync' and 'Run app' in AndroidStudio's menu

5.after build finished,you can find the library(*.so or *.a) in the directory below:

{project dir}/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug

attention that the library you build does not linked to any other library but only the c++ standard. if you want to do that you can using 'target_link_libraries' command